# The last packet successfully received from the server was 45915 seconds ago

Tags: mysql, hibernate

Website is running at the client's server and we got the following exception...

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received from the server was 45915 seconds ago.The last packet sent successfully to the server was 45915 seconds ago, which is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem. 
at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor268.newInstance(Unknown Source) 
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) 
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526) 
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406) 
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1074) 
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3246) 
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1917) 
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2060) 
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2542) 
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1734) 
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1885) 
at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:186) 
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1787) 
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:674) 
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:236) 
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2220) 
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2104) 
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2099) 
at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:94) 
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1569) 
at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:283) 
at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.uniqueResult(CriteriaImpl.java:305)
.........
```

My question is how JDBC driver decide the seconds `45915`? Is there any variable stored in MySQL server for connection of particular database? How to get details of last established connection to MySQL and other information related to connection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JDBC connection timeout cannot reconnect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26422632/jdbc-connection-timeout-cannot-reconnect)